# iOS: NSDateFormatter current date with millisecond showing dashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to implement NSDate to generate the current date with the following format:

```
 2017-06-14T15:38.000Z
```

I tried the following implementation:

```
-(void)currentDate
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
    formatter.timeZone = destinationTimeZone;
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
}
```

But this is the format date string I'm getting:

```
2017-06-14T14:08:56.-0700
```

Any of you knows how can set my NSDateFormatter to get the following date format:

```
2017-06-14T15:38.000Z
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: .000Z is not miliseconds, is time diference respect to UTC time

Comment: @ReinierMelian, can you explain?

Comment: this format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ is year, month, day and time in Hours, Minutes, and Seconds and the ZZZ is the time difference respect to UTC time .-0700 means that you have -7hrs difference

Comment: @ReinierMelian, you mean 2017-06-14T15:38.000Z is 000 difference respect to UTC time?

Comment: yes, this dateTime String come from backend?, then Date is in UTC time 000Z I think

Comment: check this website http://nsdateformatter.com/ the pattern you need is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.ZZZ`

Comment: It is not clear what your time `2017-06-14T15:38.000Z` represents. The `38` is surely minutes, but what is the `.000` - is it the seconds as a decimal fraction of a minute? If the `.000` is meant to be fractions of a second then where are the seconds themselves?  I don't know that `NSDateFormatter` supports fractions of a minute, it does support fractions of a second - `s` for whole seconds, `S` for fractions, so `ss.SSS` is seconds with milliseconds. The `Z` probably means "Zulu time", an alternative designation for UTC, indicating that the time is in UTC.

Comment: Second guess is you want an ISO 8601 format but the seconds are missing. Apple's `NSISO8601DateFormatter` class does not appear to support fractions of a second, try looking at [Peter Hosey's ISO 8601](https://web.archive.org/web/20150215110147/http://boredzo.org:80/iso8601dateformatter/) formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `NSDateFormatter`'s time zone as `systemTimeZone`. So the output always will be your device's time zone (-7h w.r.t UTC time).

**Here's with the fix:**

```
-(void)currentDate
{
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
    formatter.timeZone = destinationTimeZone;
    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ZZZ"];
    NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
2017-06-15T05:11:35.+0000
```